# Cross Origin Resource Sharing with PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, ajax.request, cors

I am having some trouble with Cross Origin Resource Sharing and Prototype. I have a simple post request to a foreign resource, and for a simple post request there are some rules that must be satisfied:

the Content-Type must be on of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, a simple request does not set custom headers with the http Request, and the Server must set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header correct.

with a vanilla JavaScript XMLHttpRequest everything works fine but with PrototypeJS it won't work because it seams Prototype sets some custom headers and I don't know how to prevent it.

I tried it in Prototype via:

```
new Ajax.Request('some.foreign-host.com/res.php', {
  method: 'post',
  postBody: 'foo=bar', 
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
  onSuccess: function(e){
    // some custom code
  }
});
```

Any idea how to get Prototype to send such a simple CORS Request?

---

I have a dump of the Headers created by a plain **JavaScript XMLHttpRequest**:

```
POST /bthesis/returnJSON.php HTTP/1.1    
Host: foreign-host.com                         
Connection: keep-alive                   
Referer: this-host.com
Content-Length: 9                        
Origin: this-host.com     
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*                              
User-Agent: [...]
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch       
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

and the Headers created by a **Prototype Request**:

```
OPTIONS /bthesis/returnJSON.php HTTP/1.1 
Host: foreign-host.com                        
Connection: keep-alive                   
Referer: this-host.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST      
Origin: this-host.com      
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With, Content-type, Accept
Accept: */*                              
User-Agent: [...]
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch       
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Prototype uses a totally different header set... which leads to following error in the console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load foreign-host.com/bthesis/returnJSON.php. Request header field X-Prototype-Version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
Refused to get unsafe header "X-JSON"

The strange thing is, that the Webserver returns in both cases the requested resource (I see it in the 'Resources' View of the developer console in chrome) but it seams that prototype has no access to it somehow

Answer (score 12):

I'm having the same problem. The link @mplungjan shared contains the answer :

You simply have to let the browser know that the `x-json` header is safe by using the `access-control-expose-headers`

I'm using this line in Ruby on Rails controller

```
  headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'x-json'
```

(This should be quite easy to translate into other programming languages :) )

More details on this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at PREFLIGHT here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Your issue is that Fx is reacting to the custom headers (X-...) and will trigger preflighting.
You will need to have the server return all access-control headers for OPTIONS and POST and have it allow custom headers.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution on [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300045/1483). And it works for me -- [details are here](http://kourge.net/node/131).

To sum up -- you need `onCreate` event in your `Ajax.Request` which removes non-standard headers:

```
    onCreate: function(response) { // here comes the fix
        var t = response.transport; 
        t.setRequestHeader = t.setRequestHeader.wrap(function(original, k, v) { 
            if (/^(accept|accept-language|content-language)$/i.test(k)) 
                return original(k, v); 
            if (/^content-type$/i.test(k) && 
                /^(application\/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart\/form-data|text\/plain)(;.+)?$/i.test(v)) 
                return original(k, v); 
            return; 
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the origin header yourself in the Ajax Request, like so

```
new Ajax.Request('some.foreign-host.com/res.php', {
    method: 'post',
    postBody: 'foo=bar',
    requestHeaders: {Origin: 'http://www.my.local-host.com'}
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    onSuccess: function(e){
        // some custom code
    }
});
```

Never tried it myself though...
What happens with the Prototype version? Is a request being issued and then nothing returns, or is a response being discarded, or what?