# Prototype AJAX request being sent as OPTIONS rather than GET; results in 501 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, prototypejs

I'm attempting to access a web service with Prototype/AJAX and am running into an error I can't figure out: it seems that when I make a request to a server my request is interpreted as an OPTIONS rather than a GET request (and in turn throws a 501 - not implemented error since the server only allows GET requests, based on what I understand from `Access-Control-Request-Method:`). Am I missing something in my AJAX/request formulation that may be causing this error? I've read a bit into CORS/preflighted requests [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests) but I'm unsure how it could apply when my code looks compliant...

Here's the relevant AJAX request:

```
function fetchMetar() {
var station_id = $("station_input").value;

    new Ajax.Request(REQUEST_ADDRESS, {
        method: "get",
        parameters: {stationString: station_id},
        onSuccess: displayMetar,
        onFailure: function() {
            $("errors").update("an error occurred");
        }
    });
}
```

and here's the error and relevant request info I get from Chrome:

```
Request URL:http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?
 dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3
 &mostRecent=true&stationString=&stationString=KSBA
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:501 Not Implemented
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, x-prototype-version, x-requested-with, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:weather.aero
Origin:http://domain.com
Referer:http://domain.com/.../...html
```

What could I be overlooking here? Why does Chrome say the request is being sent as OPTIONS rather than GET? When Chrome spits out the `Access-Control-Request-Headers:` information, are these exclusively the only headers allowed in the request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Too many hours looking for a correct fix on prototypejs... finally, we have a non-intrusive solution on [great kourge (Wilson Lee) article](http://kourge.net/node/131)!. Here is an excerpt:

> Most major Ajax frameworks like to set custom HTTP headers on the Ajax requests you instantiate; the most popular header is X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest. Consequently your request is promoted to a preflighted one and fails. **The fix is to prevent your JavaScript framework from setting these custom headers** if your request is a cross-domain one. jQuery already cleverly avoids unintentionally preflighting requests by not setting custom headers if your URL is considered to be remote. You'd have to manually prevent this if you're using other frameworks.

It can be so simple as:

```
new Ajax.Request('http://www.external-domain.net/my_api.php?getParameterKey=getParameterValue', {
            method:'post',
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            postBody:'key=' + value,
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                // process response
            },
            onCreate: function(response) { // here comes the fix
                var t = response.transport; 
                t.setRequestHeader = t.setRequestHeader.wrap(function(original, k, v) { 
                    if (/^(accept|accept-language|content-language)$/i.test(k)) 
                        return original(k, v); 
                    if (/^content-type$/i.test(k) && 
                        /^(application\/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart\/form-data|text\/plain)(;.+)?$/i.test(v)) 
                        return original(k, v); 
                    return; 
                }); 
            } 
        });
```

If you see any disadvantage/improvement to this solution, we welcome you to share :)

Comment: After hours of searching, i found this answer and it was exactly what I required :)

Answer (score 6):

In fact it is [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests), because Prototype adds custom headers [X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/) to the request. Because of these headers browser sends first `OPTIONS` request. [XHR spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) says:

> For non same origin requests using the HTTP GET method a preflight request is made when headers other than Accept and Accept-Language are set.

How to solve this problem? I can see only one possibility to solve this ASAP: completely overwrite method `Ajax.Request#setRequestHeaders()`, e.g. insert this script right after Prototype.js:

```
Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders = function() {
  var headers = {
    // These two custom headers cause preflight request:
    //'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    //'X-Prototype-Version': Prototype.Version,
    'Accept': 'text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*'
  };

  if (this.method == 'post') {
    headers['Content-Type'] = this.options.contentType +
      (this.options.encoding ? '; charset=' + this.options.encoding : '');

    /* Force "Connection: close" for older Mozilla browsers to work
     * around a bug where XMLHttpRequest sends an incorrect
     * Content-length header. See Mozilla Bugzilla #246651.
     */
    if (this.transport.overrideMimeType &&
        (navigator.userAgent.match(/Gecko\/(\d{4})/) || [0,2005])[1] < 2005)
          headers['Connection'] = 'close';
  }

  if (typeof this.options.requestHeaders == 'object') {
    var extras = this.options.requestHeaders;

    if (Object.isFunction(extras.push))
      for (var i = 0, length = extras.length; i < length; i += 2)
        headers[extras[i]] = extras[i+1];
    else
      $H(extras).each(function(pair) { headers[pair.key] = pair.value; });
  }

  for (var name in headers)
    this.transport.setRequestHeader(name, headers[name]);
}
```

This patch removes custom headers from any AJAX request. In case when you still need these headers for non-CORS requests, more logic may be added which will give possibility to disable these headers in options for `new Ajax.Request()` (I'll skip this variant here to make answer shorter).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's much easier with Prototype.js V1.7:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
    onCreate:function(r){
        r.options.requestHeaders={
        'X-Prototype-Version':null,
        'X-Requested-With':null
        };
    }
});
```

Prototype.js drops any pre-defined header if its value is null.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Prototype and i'm not sure how much use i'll be. But I had a quick look at the docs and I didn't see any support for method and parameters.

So try:

```
new Ajax.Request(REQUEST_ADDRESS+"?stationString="+station_id, {
    onSuccess: displayMetar,
    onFailure: function() {
        $("errors").update("an error occurred");
    }
});
```

Also I just noticed that stationString in your example should be in quotes assuming it isn't a variable.

Comment: Ah, Prototype definitely supports method and params for requests - I'm not sure that the problem lies there (having used this exact syntax for requests in the past, though slightly changed of course for different params/servers). I'll keep toying with the syntax though...

Comment: Just to check, is REQUEST_ADDRESS a relative/absolute URL? As in not with "http://". It seems modern browsers restrict cross-domain requests due to security concerns. Explained in the answers [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request). In short, make sure that the REQUEST_ADDRESS that you are doing the request to matches the host domain where the call is coming from

Comment: It is indeed an absolute URL - the web service I'm trying to access is outside the host domain where the request originates. However, I've worked with other web services before (the [Last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api), for example) where cross-domain requests haven't caused a problem... Why would that be (is it something server-specific)? If I'm trying to make a request to another server, how can get around the limit of same-domain requests? Based on your link (thanks, btw), it's looking like header manipulation...

Comment: Hmm... it's a stretch but you could try setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I can't see it making much of a difference seeing as it's from the same domain anyways... other than that i'm fresh out of ideas mate.

Comment: It is server specific - the server MUST set a header that allows Cross Origin Requests. To get around this you can write a proxy script that passes the information back and forth to your AjaxRequest. It also will allow you to manipulate it or cache it if you want. The Wikipedia article [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) explains a simple example.