# AngularJS CORS request custom header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I'm having trouble getting CORS enabled on my server in combination with AngularJS. I'm using Angular 1.2.16 and this is my server config:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name, Authorization"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

I can use the following request:

```
$http.post(configuration.authUrl, {username: 'username', password: 'password'})
    .success(function (data) {
         $cookieStore.put(configuration.sessionName, {
             token: data.authenticationToken,
              user: data.user
         });
    })
    .error(function () {}));
```

since this request doesn't use a custom header.

When I afterwards try to request the following:
`Balance.get()` with Balance being:

```
angular.module('portalApp')
    .factory('Balance', ['$resource', 'Auth', 'configuration', function ($resource, Auth, configuration) {
        return $resource(configuration.balanceUrl, {}, {
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: Auth.getAuthToken()
                }
            }
        });
    }]);
```

I get a `401 Unauthorized` on the balanceUrl.

In the config I have put:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I even tried putting `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = Auth.getAuthToken();` before the `$resource` in the `Balance` resource factory but that didn't help.

The headers being sent to the preflight `OPTIONS` request don't have the `Authorization` header, no matter what method I use. These are the request headers of the preflight `OPTIONS` request.

```
OPTIONS /api/v1.0/user/orders HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: referer
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research I found out the problem wasn't occurring because of the AngularJS or Apache configuration. It was a problem in the backend server app (Java). The urls were restricted for all HTTP methods, so when AngularJS wants to execute the preflight `OPTIONS` request, the access was denied and a `401` was returned.

This was fixed by doing:

```
if(!authenticationService.isTokenValid(glueToken) && !((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.toString()) ){
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
} else {
  filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

In stead of:

```
if(!authenticationService.isTokenValid(glueToken)){
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
} else {
  filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I know you can't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not anonymously (don't perform authentication or authorization) allow the options pre-flight request.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21458845/101662

Comment: That's what I do in my own answer so yes, that works

Comment: Sounded like the options was failing though?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using quite a different approach but the premise is still the same.

First try putting Bearer in front of your access token:

```
headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + Auth.getAuthToken()
}
```

If not try this:
app.config may not work if you don't have app set up as a variable, so you may need to adjust.

```
app.config(
    function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Auth.getAuthToken();
    }
);
```