# Web API 2 Cors Request Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get CORS set up for a project I am working on with WebAPI 2. I started having issues, so I created a demo app directly from asp.net forums [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). Everything was working correctly until I needed to use json as the content type. Then I started getting:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I understand with this content type sends preflight requests, but I am dumbfounded how I can get this to pass. Am I missing something? As soon as I remove the "contentType: 'application/json'" attribute from AJAX request, it works.

TestController.cs

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("GET: Test message")
        };
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string name)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("POST: Test message")
        };
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("PUT: Test message")
        };
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Ajax Request

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:17515/',
            data: JSON.stringify("Test"),
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed) web api 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649361/options-405-method-not-allowed-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

It client will first send an `OPTIONS` request to the server. To this request, the server should add a header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:17822
```

This indicates that the API running on port 17515 accepts requests from the client served by port 17822.

You could try changing your attribute to:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:17822", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

We haven't had good experiences using `EnableCors`, so we handle OPTIONS requests using OWIN, simply returning 200 OK and manually adding the appropriate headers to all OPTIONS request sent by approved origins.

There is a good article on CORS on MSDN (likely you have already seen it): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your WebApiConfig.cs, you could try enabling the cors attributes there instead of on the controller.

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

rather than just

```
        config.EnableCors();
```

This is working on a test project I have running at the moment.