# Why is this AJAX request in my ASP.NET MVC site triggering a preflight check?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and one of the pages has some JavaScript that calls an API on a server that is running an ASP.NET WebApi project.  The two projects normally run on different domains, but locally they are just on different ports on `localhost`.  This JavaScript is making a `GET` request, but when I watch the network log an `OPTIONS` request is being made instead, and the WebApi returns `405 Method Not Authorized`.

From my research, I know that [this is a "preflight" check that is sometimes triggered for AJAX calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), and I know that [ASP.NET WebApi doesn't support `OPTIONS` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26649361/2747593), so that's why I'm getting the 405.  However, [the preflight check is supposed to be skipped when certain conditions are met](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#how-cors-works), and those conditions have been met here.  See for yourself; the following is the (anonymized) entirety of the JS code for the AJAX request:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:12345/api/SomeAction?someArg=" + someArg;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
    // [snip], process the result here
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Why is this simple request triggering a preflight check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to some additional JavaScript loaded by Application Insights in the MVC project.

I discovered this by stepping into the `xmlhttp.send()` call with the debugger, where I eventually noticed I was in `ai.0.js`.  That file from AppInsights overrides the definition of `XMLHttpRequest`, and [adds a couple custom headers to the request](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/ajax/ajax.ts#L147), which causes the preflight check to be required.

Thus there are two possible solutions:

1. Disable Application Insights and remove its custom JavaScript.
2. Implement `OPTIONS` handling in the API project.

[Supporting `OPTIONS` is likely the better solution](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html), so I will likely do that eventually, but removing AppInsights is faster, so I'm doing that for now.  I removed the `<script>` tag that started with `var appInsights = window.appInsights...` in my `_Layout.cshtml` view, and that fixed the issue.

Comment: you should also post this as an issue on the AI javascript sdk https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues .  I don't know why the presence of AI would be forcing a CORS check by the browser.

Comment: @JohnGardner: I hadn't posted an issue there because I didn't think it was necessarily a bug, just an unfortunate side-effect. I believe it is the custom headers that AI adds that forces the preflight check (see the file on GitHub I linked to in my answer). Let me know if you think it actually is a bug, and I can open up an issue.