# Enable CORS in Umbraco 6 / Web API 2 Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, umbraco

I'm a newer developer who has been developing a RESTful API with Web API 2 within an instance of Umbraco 6.  After some research on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api, I added the attribute to my controller as such:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com,http://example.local", headers: "*", methods: "*")] //CORS TESTING
public class PropertiesController : UmbracoApiController
{
  //Code Hidden
}
```

I'm finding that I can go to a site like http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate and pull in my JSON through the endpoint URL and validate it even though I didn't allow that host to call my API.

Following the instructions from the asp.net link above, I noticed that my solution doesn't have an "App_Start" folder with a WebApiConfig.CS file, so I was never able to add the `config.EnableCors();` code which I think may be the underlying issue?  I'm not sure how to continue at this point because to get this far, I just had to add a new `Web API Controller Class` to '/App_Code' and then inherit `UmbracoApiController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the WebApiConfig.cs if you wish and call it from Global.asax.cs . Or just call EnableCors() wherever you have the config. This is a simple answer with an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397652/3520146 .