# Post JSON data using jquery in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I use this code in my html page to post json data to server using toggle switch ( depending on the value of toggle switch)

```
  $('#ledToggle').change(function () {
      var ledState = $(this).prop('checked');
      var body = {
          //Key: "1",
          LedState: ledState
      };
      console.log(body);
      body1 = JSON.stringify(body);
      console.log(body1);

      return $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:8060/api/led",
          data: JSON.stringify(body),
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json"
      });
```

But it always give me response 405 "`Method not allowed`" in Mozilla and "`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8060/api/led. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`" in Chrome.

And when I uses Postman or fiddler to post it posts normally.

Comment: Where is your html page running from? Do you have it on localhost?

Comment: It runs on the same PC that runs the API

Comment: What is the URL of the original html page? Can you paste it in here?

Comment: It's a cross origin request with a content-type you can't generate with a form. It gets preflighted. The server is 405ing because it doesn't support OPTION requests. No need to keep asking questions to figure out what is going on. The duplicate question explains what is going on.

Comment: I didn't publish it. file:///C:/projects/temp/IOT.Web/IOT.Web/LED.html

Comment: @Quentin thank you I will see if the answers help me or not

Comment: @bilal For a page to run ajax, it needs to be hosted. Browsers prevent `file://` from doing ajax for security reasons. Once it is hosted then you might still get a problem with CORS as @Quentin suggests. Please update your question with the URL in it as others might have the same problem.

Comment: So if I publish it, it will work?

Comment: @Quentin I figured out the problem but I didn't found a solution

Comment: The solution is to either (a) Not make a cross origin request (b) Not format the request as Ajax or (c) Configure the server to respond correctly to the OPTIONS request with permission for the foreign origin to make the request

Comment: Thank you for helping e to understand the problem. I use the solution in this question to enable cors in API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024313/asp-net-webapi2-enable-cors-not-working-with-aspnet-webapi-cors-5-2-3