# CORS error when sending request to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am trying to send a request from an angular application and an ASP.NET web API both running in localhost on two different ports. When sending a request from the angular app(frontend) to the Web API I am getting a CORS error that "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

I tried a lot of ways to try to solve this issue like enabling cors in the WebApiConfig class, custom headers in the web.config and intercepting pre-flight checks but still, the issue occurred.

WebApiConfig.cs

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, 
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested- 
            With, X- AuthToken" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, 
                 DELETE, OPTIONS" />
   </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <add name="HandleOptions" type="OptionsModule" />
   </modules>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619656/enable-cors-in-web-api-2 Mosharaf Hossain answer worked for me

Comment: Also have look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Comment: @AmitBaranes tried it but the error still occurs

Comment: @Nik That was the first document I read

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the site you requested doesn't allows any resources to be accessed from any other domain. Means the site you have requested has not implemented CORS (cross origin request sharing).

**Temporary solution:**
You can use a proxy (https://crossorigin.me/https://google.com), all you need to do --> just append https://crossorigin.me/ before your `url` and for more details

Check [HERE](https://corsproxy.github.io/) .

**Second and permanent solution:** 
That you have to implement cross origin resource sharing for the site you are requesting resources from.

**Third one:** 
3rd is you can disable CORS from your browser (https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/).

Check these sites for more details[1](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/),[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: The problem is that I have implemented CORS on my api but it still doesn't work.

Comment: kindly check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024313/asp-net-webapi2-enable-cors-not-working-with-aspnet-webapi-cors-5-2-3

Comment: I have tried all of these but the problem still persists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199757/enable-options-header-for-cors-on-net-core-web-api

Comment: is last url helpful because i'm not able to find any issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you declared EnableCors in both WebApiConfig.cs and Web.config.
This usually gives cors error saying something like:

```
'....origin 'www.example.com' blocked by cors policy due to multiple No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'('*','*').'
```

You should uncomment in either web-api.config or web.config and try.

Answer (score 0):

This error you will get using different port numbers between MVC and Web Rest API. So you have to change post or get request header allows methods "true". So if you have to change in web API two places then, you can resolve this error in MVC with web Api

1. Go to App_Start folder and open WebAPIConfig.cs file.
2. Just add this line "config.EnableCors();  with namespace "using system.web.http;
3. Go to api controller and add this line in top of Controller, "[EnableCors("*","*","*")], Inside all double quotation need to add star * symbol.
4. You can add Action method level in same code.
5. [EnableCors("*","*","*")] in controller code.