# Set http header on angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my app I have a list of building on webService and wanna get them with `http` with Angular2.
I created a service for that and here is I code wrote for it:

**My http service:**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptionsArgs, Http, Response, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { StaticValuesService } from './static-values.service';
import { Building } from '../model/building';

@Injectable()
export class BuildingService {

  constructor(private _http: Http, private _values: StaticValuesService) {}

  getAllBuildings() {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.get(this._values.MainApi + 'api/getbuildings/', options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());

  }

}
```

And I subscribe in a component with this code:

```
constructor(private _buildingServices: BuildingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._buildingServices.getAllBuildings().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

After I run the angular server look like the `contnet-type` is not set in header of the request! and the result of that is a 404 error on console!

[image]

**Request content in network chrome**:

```
OPTIONS /api/getbuildings/ HTTP/1.1
Host: nommix-api.azurewebsites.net
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/dashboard/master
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0
```

**Response header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 134
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=12a1bb0d03776b567fa3d04e126a9fa5ad153cba2c87fbc48fc25d775bebd44a;Path=/;Domain=nommix-api.azurewebsites.net
Date: Thu, 02 Feb 2017 11:51:25 GMT
```

When i tested API with Postman it's work correctly.

Why it doesn't work? and how can I fixed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume that you config proxy by this tutorial https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#proxy-to-backend

try to enable CORS in your backend webservice

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
```

enable `OPTIONS` method in ASP.net app
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21458845/3676586

Comment: I already set proxy and `access-control` is enabled as well. but still doesn't work. when I use tools like postman everything work properly!

Comment: did you protected this route, for example to access this url, you must authenticated, as i see, your code `headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ');` do not have token. btw, postman do not concern about CORS, make sure you allow get/post/options methods.

Comment: I added `Authorization` just for test purpose. in my end-point (api/getbuildings/) we have a list of the building, that's it. without auth or anything else. and also without `headers.apped('Auth....)'` I still have same error.

Comment: ok, let try another solution, do not use proxy, because you enabled CORS, so use api end-point directly to http://nommix-api.azurewebsites.net

Comment: btw could you provide response header, as i see when request `http://nommix-api.azurewebsites.net/api/getbuildings/` the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type` only accept `Content-Type`, so you could add `Authorization` header as well.

Comment: please read this topic, it seem you do not enable options method, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21458845/3676586