# Why httpOptions method does not work when I put a Rout tag in a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem that I don't know why is ocurring.

What I want is to call a method in my web api, the httpOptions verb should return me a HttpOkStatus but instead it returns a 404 error. This is only happening if I put the tag 
 `[Route("MyRoute")]`, otherwise it work perfectly.

My question is, why it does not work when I put the tag on it?.

I have this code

```
[Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/MergedSchemas")]
    public class MergedSchemasController : ApiController
    {


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Schemas")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetSchemas(string formName)
        {
          //Some code
        }
}
```

In the Global.asax I have this code:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new OptionsHttpMessageHandler());
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }

    public class OptionsHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
            {
                var apiExplorer = 
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();

                var controllerRequested = request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;
                var supportedMethods = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions.Where(d =>
                {
                    var controller = d.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
                    return string.Equals(
                        controller, controllerRequested, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                })
                .Select(d => d.HttpMethod.Method)
                .Distinct();

                if (!supportedMethods.Any())
                    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", string.Join(",", supportedMethods));
                    return resp;
                });
            }

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        }
    }
```

The uri I am calling is : `/api/MergedSchemas/Schemas?formName=frmBCOSEG`

Thank you!

Comment: The tag Route() is expecting you to give it a route not a name.  Example (Route[("api/action")]

Comment: Yes but when I call the Options method it returns me and error.

Comment: what is an " Options method" you may want to show us some code

Comment: I want to call the method with the HttpOptions verb and it should always return a HttpOkStatus,
Wait a seccond, I will post some code.

Comment: When asking a question on SO, 99.99% of the time, we cannot help without code.  In general its a good idea to always include pertinent code in the question.  We're going to ask for it anyway.

Comment: There you go, some code :)

Comment: can you show us what's  the url you're calling ?

Comment: Have you enabled attribute routing?

Comment: /api/MergedSchemas/Schemas?formName=frmBCOSEG

Comment: @Amy mmm maybe not... How do I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Oh, yes it is done ;(

Comment: The rout tag works good. The thing is that when i call that method with HttpOptions verb, it does not work.

Comment: You specified `HttpGet`, so the Action will only react to GET requests, not to OPTIONS requests....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support HTTP OPTIONS verb in ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095777/how-to-support-http-options-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-webapi-application)

Comment: @NineBerry it response to options becouse of the code that I wrote in OptionsHttpMessageHandler class.

The prove is that if I remove the route tag it response to HttpOptions.

Comment: It's unclear why you deleted your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343747/cant-use-my-web-api-with-option-verb-web-api-asp-net-c-sharp#comment83673038_48343747) about this, just to ask it again.

Comment: "What I want is to call a method in my web api, the options should return me a HttpOkStatus but instead it returns a 404 error. This is only happening if I put the tag  [Route("MyRoute")], otherwise it work perfectly.".

I thought that in that sentece I included it. Sorry, english is not my first lenguage as you can tell haha.

Comment: I think what is wrong is with this line: 

                var controllerRequested = request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;   in OptionsHttpMessageHandler class.

Probably is not getting the route correctly becouse of the tags

Comment: @PabloSalazar, `request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"]` only runs  `if(request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)` which is not the case, as you call your api using http verb GET, not OPTIONS. I have tested your code and it works here. The issue cannot be reproduced using what you posted in your question.