# pages indexed by google without content load via ajax

Tags: angularjs, indexing, cors, xmlhttprequest, google-index

The main problem is my website's pages in `google cached` are not complete, they have no data, because of `XHR` errors, here are some details:

I implemented my website using `AngularJs`, It works correctly on any browsers and locations I've tested.
Google says, "`Google Search Engine` sees exactly what `modern browsers` display", but my website has not indexed correctly yet, so there is a problem in my codes!

I've been struggling with google to introduce my website's pages completely to Google, but all I've gotten is pages with non-filled controls and without any data that loads via Angular. When I check my website on `Google Live Test`, I get this kind of errors in `Page Resources`: "`Couldn't be loaded`"
Some of these errors are related to images that don't matter right now, but the emergency problem is that most of `XHR`s couldn't be loaded!
There is no detail to know what is the exact issue, but when I'd checked my website cached pages on google I saw this error on developer tools:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '…' from origin
>   'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I added these tags to my web.config but there is no change in Live Test and Google Index:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value=" content-type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
```

could you please tell me what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Your web server (IIS?) doesn't handle the OPTIONS method that is the preflight request correctly. This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/21458845/3574481

Comment: @peeebeee Thank you for your comment, I found the solution from this URL although not that one you shared the link, but the confirmed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from these links:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19100808/3247491
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

First I removed these codes from web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Then I added the CORS NuGet package

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Next add `config.EnableCors();` to `webApiConfig`,

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

and finally add this attribute to all apiControllers

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", PreflightMaxAge = TimeSpan.TicksPerDay)]
```

now google can see pages correctly.