# how to garmin login using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oauth, garmin

Im trying to implement an Oauth1 login to garmins using Angular2 and regular http calls, but on the first call to oauth/request_token path i get a pre-flight OPTIONS call error seems not having CORS enabled or something.

It may anyone tried or did this before?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with CORS issues?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Which API url are you using for Garmin?

Comment: @JonathanM im using http://connectapi.garmin.com/oauth-service-1.0/oauth/request_token as provided to us on the documentation. Yes im familiar with CORS issues and on this case the response for the OPTION call is not returning in the header the Access-Control-Allow-Origin key

Comment: Hmmm. Can you post the response?

Comment: The response was denied with code 501 Not Implemented, headers were Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection:close
Content-Length:317
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 20 Mar 2017 22:44:48 GMT
Expires:Mon, 20 Mar 2017 22:44:48 GMT
Mime-Version:1.0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:AkamaiGHost

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: While it deals with a different framework, this answer could be enlightening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814739/prototype-ajax-request-being-sent-as-options-rather-than-get-results-in-501-err#15300045

Comment: @JonathanM but this is not the case, since is an ajax request the pre-flight request OPTION will be trigger by the browser is not attach to any framework and the issue here seems to be that garmins server does not have the CORS enabled

Comment: Do you have the text of the request? There may be elements in the request that are tripping up the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138678/discussion-between-bitgandtter-and-jonathan-m).

Comment: Is this public API ?
if so please share the API docs link

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `Origin` in your header (my suggestion is to do it with an interceptor) and then in your server config allow your domain or localhost:port to access it.